# Error: Too many re-renders. because i changed setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, use-state

error: Too many re-renders.
explaining code: (
iam maping array of object - in that mapping funtion i maked new array of objects( `raiting = [..rating, {}]` )
then set useState state to be that  array of objects ( `setRatingFinal([...rating])` )
and then final i display that - but iam getting error.
)
Can somebody write me answer for this, if its posible to write code in answer.
Thanks.

```
var [ratingFinal, setRatingFinal] = useState([])
var rating = []

movies.map((movie, i) => {
  rating =  [...rating, {index: i, value: movie["IMDB Votes"] * movie["IMDB Rating"]}];
});

setRatingFinal([...rating])   **//because of this is error**


  return (
    <div>
      {ratingFinal.map((movie, i) => {
        <div key={i}>{movie.value}</div>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the movies is array of 3021 objects - example of one object in that array -

```
{"IMDB Rating": 6.3, "IMDB Votes": 365}
```

i tryed without `var rating` just with `ratingFinal`, but and that dont work-  like this:

```
 var [ratingFinal, setRatingFinal] = useState([])
    
    movies.map((movie, i) => {
      setRatingFinal([...ratingFinal, {index: i, value: movie["IMDB Votes"] * movie["IMDB Rating"]}]);
    });
    
      return (
        <div>
          {ratingFinal.map((movie, i) => {
            <div key={i}>{movie.value}</div>
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make timeout and move `setRatingFinal([...rating])` in timeout minimum 100ms,
and you must make one objec with value because in first render it will not show (it can't read property of undefined)

```
 var [ratingFinal, setRatingFinal] = useState([{value: 'something'}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `.map()` method incorrectly - if you'd like to keep the syntax use `.forEach()`.

Map returns a new array so the usage is:

```
const rating = test.map((movie, i) => { 
  return {index: i, value: movie["IMDB Votes"] * movie["IMDB Rating"]}
});

setRatingFinal(rating)
```

Comment: Hi, i tryed this and the same error - i think the problem is with setRatingFinal, not because maping  function. but Thanks for answering